# How can I center my header image?

Tags: fix-my-code, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I think this is immaterial, but just for the record: I'm building a Joomla 3.4.3 website with my own Bootstrap 3 template.

The header image `banner.svg` on my [website](http://dev.shespeakswithpassionmembership.com/index.php) should be in the center. So what I did was: give the image this CSS:

```
header img {
   margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}
```

But, whatever I do, the image will stay on the left, unless I give it a fixed margin:

```
header img {
    margin: 10px 90px 0 90px;
}
```

but I don't want to do that for obivious reasons: scaling for responsiveness.

The header image 'shrinks' on scroll (jQuery), but I don't see any connection there.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to set the wrapper container to 100% with:

```
.navbar-header {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then, for the image, you need to make it a block element and set the margins correctly, like so:

```
header.large img {
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 900px;
    display: block
}
```

Comment: Some people are so much better in intricate CSS matters. I vaguely remembered something along the lines of a containing element, but....

So thanks a lot, Lodder.

I have one question though: as you can see the changes, when you scroll down the image becomes smaller (onscroll jQuery effect), but the containing element .navbar-header blocks the menu items from positioning alongside of the logo. Could you give a hint of a solution here?

Comment: Try assigning `width: auto;` to the `.navbar-header` class on scroll. I'm not sure as to where this scroll function is coming from so can't give an exact answer, but I tried adding this value in Firebug and it displayed the menu in your desired position

Comment: I guess I know too little of JavaScript/jQuery to do that, so I'll ask about this on a jQuery forum. Thanx a million, Lodder!